# Raster calculations with values from CSV file. Iteration through attribute table

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am using GIS 3.14.16. I am working with a raster layer and a table with n multipliers in CSV format. 
I would like to create n new rasters:

```
raster1 = raster * CSV$row1
raster2 = raster * CSV$row2
etc.
```

The goal is to automate this process using iteration, with n=len(csv.rows).
Is it possible to build it in Graphical Modeler?

I am attaching screenschot with the scheme of the model I would like to build.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution to this problem, without using Python script, neither graphical modeler. 
The first step is to convert the values from CSV file to n separate rasters and then to use a raster calculator for the calculations.

1. **'Create constant raster layer'**
   Creating a raster for each value from attribute table.

- Use drag&drop to load the file with attributes to the project.
- For iterating over an attribute table, the batch process and expression editor have to be used.
- Open 'Create constant raster layer' as batch process.
- Constant value (calculate according to expression) =  
   to_real(attribute(**get_feature_by_id**('attribute_table_variable_chosen_from_expression_editor', @row_number+1), 'column_name'))
  [image]
  [image]

2. Raster calculator as a batch process 
   A - input raster
   B - n rasters with values 
   [image]